# Fixing position for Algorithm2e does not work

Tags: positioning, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

I have the following minimal example. When I compile this, the result is fine, as expected.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{floatrow}
 \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\myworries[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 

\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{Se}

In this section, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
In this section, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
In this section, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
In this section, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
In this section, ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,


 \subsection{Constraints}

constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\


where n is the minimum/maximum

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{RDF}
\KwResult{Violation}    
$Violation$\;
\end{algorithm}        

The algorithm for . The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .
The algorithm for . The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .The algorithm for .

 \subsection{Constraint}
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\
constraints\\


where d is the where d is the where d is the where d is the where d is the 

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{RDF}
\KwResult{violation}
$Violation$
$Violation$\;
$Violation$
$Violation$\;

\caption{Algorithm to...}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

But in my main document, the algorithms go to the next page, whereas there are enough space in the current page. I provided also one example page.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Example from the main doc]

Comment: all the warnings about `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58--59` are due to mis-use of `\\ ` which should never be used at the end of a paragraph. It will result in very poor spacing in the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I edit the post now. Also I will remove \\

Comment: start from a copy of the original docuemnt and just restrict to that section you should be able to make an example that demonstrates the problem , but it doesn't look to me like it would fit in the white space above the page number 43.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I show you my log file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle even when I shorten the algorithm to 1-2 lines, it goes to the next page! In these pages, where I use algorithmic2e with [H] , there are always this free space, even the text will go to the next page.

Comment: make an example that shows the problem

Comment: Thats the problem. I cannot put the whole document here. Minimal example works fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42730/discussion-between-java-developer-and-david-carlisle).